# pass myArray by ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello I am trying to pass array called myArray to php.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var tagApi = $(".tm-input").tagsManager();
        var myArray = [];


        jQuery(".typeahead").typeahead({
            name: 'email',
            displayKey: 'email',
            source: function (query, process) {
                return $.get('Data.php', {
                    query: query
                }, function (data) {
                    data = $.parseJSON(data);
                    console.log(data);
                    return process(data);

                });
            },
            afterSelect: function (item) {
                tagApi.tagsManager("pushTag", item);
                myArray.push(item);
                console.log('This is myArray', myArray);
            }


        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Data.php",
            data: {
                myArray: myArray
            },
            success: function () {
                $("#submit").submit();
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

But when I am trying to get myArray like:

```
<?php $myArray = $_REQUEST['myArray']; 
echo "This is myArray: ".$myArray; 
?>
```

I see only echo This is my Array without any data from myArray.
How should I pass myArray to get it in php?

Submit is my button which got id submit. After submit form I just want to pass myArray and get it in my php file.

Or maybe I am doing something wrong and just myArray is empty? my console.log works good and I can see all data from myArray

Edit:
There is html section

```
<form action="Data.php" method="post" id="submit">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Add Tags:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="nope" autocomplete="off" class="typeahead tm-input form-control tm-input-info" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions form-group"><button type="submit" value="add" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Utwórz</button></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Inspect element and debug the xhr request param

Comment: Also do a `var_dump ($myArray)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Comment: @sanu var_dump says that is NULL but why

Comment: @defus did you checked the xhr request params through inspect element

Comment: @defus can you add `dataType: "json"` in your ajax options and check

Comment: @sanu yes I did i see only my Get response also see console.log and that jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: POST, dataType also doesn't works

Comment: Can you try with below answer and let.me know

Comment: @sanu I tried still nothing. I'll edit my question can you check html?

Comment: @defus before calling ajax can you verify `myArray` having data

Comment: @sanu i see data in myArray when I called console.log in afterSelect: function

Comment: @defus ajax is getting called before afterSelect method

Comment: @sanu I tried to put ajax into afterSelect and every console.log with myArray i see XHR finished loading post. But still is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling ajax inside `.ready ()` which means it will call once your document is fully loaded. You have to call the ajax when user clicks on submit button

Try this

```
  <script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var tagApi = $(".tm-input").tagsManager();
    var myArray = [];


    jQuery(".typeahead").typeahead({
        name: 'email',
        displayKey: 'email',
        source: function (query, process) {
            return $.get('Data.php', {
                query: query
            }, function (data) {
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(data);
                return process(data);

            });
        },
        afterSelect: function (item) {
            tagApi.tagsManager("pushTag", item);
            myArray.push(item);
            console.log('This is myArray', myArray);
        }


    });

  $(".btn").click (function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Data.php",
        data: {
            myArray: myArray
        },
        success: function () {
            $("#submit").submit();
        }
    });
   });
});
```

Comment: It can't by done like this because it works like this: http://demo.itsolutionstuff.com/demo/demo-php-input-multiple-tags-with-dynamic-autocomplete-exampleexample.html I want to take all tags and put in into my db

Comment: after click submit button

Comment: @defus I updated my answer please try and let me know

Comment: still myArray is null

Comment: Inspect element while clicking submit button you can see one xhr request under network tab. Click that request for more details and check is it sending your data or not

Comment: I tried add myArray into table like: $sql = "INSERT INTO test VALUES ('$myArray')"; and in my database i got value: Array without any data just text: Array. (It's works after click button ) So i Think that my array is empty and it works only in method afterSelect (hmm?)

Comment: yes this part works but still got empty Array. ANyway thank you